# Inverse Hadamard determinant inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities, determinants

As far as I remembered there is an inverse Hadamard inequality for the determinant of the form
$$
|D|>\prod_j \sqrt{(a_{jj}^2-\sum_{i\neq j}a_{ij}^2)}
$$
providing all values in $(\cdot)>0$.

Please help me with exact references to this inequality, its possible generalizations and modifications and comments.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54536/a-reverse-hadamard-inequality and http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379596891968 --- both not quite what the OP is looking for...

Comment: It is not true, take $a_{ii}=1$, other elements $-1/(n-1)+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you mean Ostrowski's theorem $$|D|>\prod_j  \left(|a_{jj}|-\sum_{i\neq j}|a_{ij}|\right)$$
for diagonally dominant matrices (see e.g. http://planetmath.org/propertiesofdiagonallydominantmatrix)?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I wanted, user35593. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know a reference to Ostrowski's paper? Is not a first proposed inequality a consequence?

Comment: Perhaps it is Ostrowski, Alexander; 
Über die determinanten mit überwiegender Hauptdiagonale.  
Comment. Math. Helv. 10 (1937), no. 1, 69–96, or A. M. Ostrowski, "Sur la determination des borns inferieures pour une class des determinants," Bulletin des Sciences Mathmatiques, vol. 61, no. 2, pp. 19–32, 1937.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson - thank you. May somebody help with a paper in Bulletin des Sciences Mathematiques? A first paper-not an easy reading...

Comment: Is the next generalization valid with two pivoted elements: let $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)$ be a line of a determinant with $a_1+a_2>\sum_{k=3}^n a_k$. Is the Ostrowski inequality still valid with a product of \prod(a_1+a_2-\sum_{k=3}^n a_k)$ -???

Comment: Note that for order $n=2$ the original inequality with squares are valid!